# Laravel One to Many relationship for system

Tags: laravel

I want to output all the reviews based on one hotel of my system. Currently, I have a system which displays ALL reviews on each hotels. I have the following code:

**PostsController:**

```
public function show($id)
{
    $post = Post::find($id);
    $review = Review::all();

    return view('posts.show', compact('post', 'review'));      
    /** return view('posts.show')->with('post', $post); */
}
```

**Posts.php:**

```
protected $tables='posts';
function review()
{
    return $this->hasMany('App\Review');
}
```

**Review.php:**

```
protected $tables='reviews';
function post()
{
    return $this->hasMany('App\Post', 'posts_title', 'title');
}
```

I want to return matching reviews for the right hotel. I want to return `posts_title` (main column in `posts` table) and return the `title` (column in the `reviews` table).

Comment: This is a bit confusing. Is a "Post" a "Hotel"? What the relationship between post, review and hotel?

Comment: Hi the post is a hotel, the review is a review of the hotel. I want to display the specific reviews for each individual hotel

Comment: I would change the "Post" class (and all mentions of it) to "Hotel". I get the feeling you may thinking in terms of the view or front-end- how the end user sees the information. You may want to review some object oriented programming. Once your application gets more complex, it will be easier to read your own code.  For example, just based on what you posted so far; It is easier to say "A Hotel has many reviews" as opposed to "a Post has many reviews". Does that make sense?

Comment: i fully understand, as i only have a limited amount of time on this project i will keep to it as post for now. However would you be able to help on this, for your sake think of posts as hotel instead.

Comment: sure. go through this when you can: https://laracasts.com/series/laravel-6-from-scratch

Comment: A few minutes reading of [the docs](https://laravel.com/docs/6.x/eloquent-relationships#one-to-many) would answer your questions - they are very good and include simple examples that are easy to use in your context.   Your `post()` relationship should be `belongsTo()` (not `hasMany()` as you have).

Comment: ... and the parameters you are passing in the relationship are wrong.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Reviews.php**

```
protected $tables ="posts";
public function reviews()
{
    return $this->hasMany('App\Reviews', 'foreign_id', 'id_here');
}
```

**PostsController**

```
public function show($title)
{
    $post = Posts::where('title', '=', $title)->with('reviews')->first();
    return view('show.blade', compact('post'));
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You have an error with your relationship, check the [one-to-many reference](https://laravel.com/docs/5.7/eloquent-relationships#one-to-many)
In your Post Model:

```php
function reviews()
{
    return $this->hasMany('App\Review');
}
```

In your Review Model:

```php
protected $tables='reviews';
function post()
{
    return $this->belongsTo('App\Post', 'post_id', 'id');
}
```

And you can use eager-loading:

```php
public function show($id)
{
    $post = Post::with('reviews')->find($id);

    return view('posts.show', compact('post'));
}
```

Comment: so instead of 'return $this...' use the $post = Post::with('reviews')->find($id); ?

Comment: ignore my comment

Comment: @cutesengh each `post` has many `reviews`, so `post` has many `reviews`. `reviews` belongs to `post`. Fix the Review model. And I think you want to display the  reviews belongs to post, so you can use eager loading method `with()` to get the reviews.

Comment: your belongsTo method assumes that posts titles are unique. If they are, that's great. Based on the level of the question, i'm doubtful. I would use id's to be safe

Comment: @aibarra I didn't notice that.

Comment: @cutesengh did u have `post_id` in your reviews table?

Comment: @TsaiKoga no prob.  I'm not use to this order, will this produce a collection or the single object?

Comment: @aibarra after `find()`, it return an post object, and this post object has an relationship reviews collection as its attribute

Comment: hi i dont have post_id. I am taking a risk because im not trying to find the information based on ID but on posts_title(hotel) and title (reviews). I know confusing

Comment: @cuteseng you better add a foreign_key for reviews.  just like aibarra said, if there are same titles, that will be a problem.

Comment: @TsaiKoga will your answer work? you didn't define a "reviews" function in Hotels. I don't think you can traverse backwards the way its being called. please compare my answer to yours

Comment: @aibarra oh, he loss 's'.

Comment: @TsaiKoga oops, sorry you're right. You don't need the belongsTo then. Only if he's going through a review and wants some "post" information, like the title.