# Laravel one to many relationship for my system

Tags: php, laravel

I want to output all the reviews based on one hotel of my system. Currently, i have a system which displays ALL reviews on each hotels. I have the following code

PostsController:

```
public function show($id)
 {
   $post = Post::find($id);
   $review = Review::all();
   return view('posts.show', compact('post', 'review')); 
 }
```

Posts.php:

```
    protected $tables='posts';
    function review()
      {
        return $this->hasMany('App\Review');
      }
     }
```

Review.php:

```
     protected $tables='reviews';
     function post()
       {
         return $this->hasMany('App\Post', 'posts_title', 'title');
       }
```

I want to return matching reviews for the right hotel. I want to return posts_title (main column in posts table) and return the title (column in the reviews table).

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Laravel One to Many relationship for system](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60017585/laravel-one-to-many-relationship-for-system)

Comment: Can you provide the database tables design for posts and reviews.

Comment: Administrative note - please do not post double/duplicate questions.  Either edit or delete your original question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check the name of the file `Posts.php` According to your `post` function in `Review` Model it has to be `Post.php`. I don't know your database structure looks like but it will be better if you use `Laravel` best practices  `id` for `primary key` and `post_id` for `foreign key`, Also i think the relation should be one to many it means one post has many reviews like that:
 `Post.php`

```
public function reviews(){
  return $this->hasMany('App\Review');
}
```

`Review.php`

```
public function post(){
  return $this->belongsTo('App\Post');
}
```

Then you can use it like

```
$post = Post::with('reviews')->whereId($id)->first();
```

To get more information you can visit https://laravel.com/docs/6.x/eloquent-relationships#one-to-many

Comment: hi, i have changed my code to match that, however i am now recieving this error: olumn not found: 1054 Unknown column 'reviews.post_id' in 'where clause' (SQL: select * from `reviews` where `reviews`.`post_id` in (2)). I dont have a column called post_ID which is strange

Comment: i also need to use both 'title' and 'post_title' as i am basing the information from the title itself. Unfortunatley using ID wont solve my problem